# Input file which contains 2D coordinates for a rectangle

Tags: java, file-io, rectangles, coordinate-systems, rect

I am struggling to read in 2D coordinates from an input file which should then create rectangles in a rectangle class. I am wondering how I would go about starting this as I am new to programming, such as how to layout the coordinates in the file and how to read them in using like a X1 Y1 X2 Y2 format to create a rectangle in the rectangle class. Thanks.

Comment: you're beginner with programming but you're already into file handling? :O can I ask you first before suggesting solution? can you use array well? do you have a background on bufferedreader? do you know how to use loop?

Comment: Start with one thing at a time. First learn how to read data from a text file then once you have that mastered then move onto how to create a Graphics Object. Once you have that one figured out then use what you've learned to put the two together. Don't try an learn everything all at once. There are lots of helpful post in SO to assist you in your endeavor.

Comment: @jace haha I have some background but not a lot, I can use loops but not very experienced with array and bufferedreader

Comment: well you have 3 problem to solve. 1: how to create GUI. 2: how to read text file. 3: how to put input files to program variables using array or list. I am currently typing the buffered reader. But that's all I can give you now since GUI is hard to teach without self study.

Comment: @jace okay thanks for your time and help! I'll carry on researching!

Answer (score 0):

Read BufferedReader from https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/ . It is an example of bufferedReader which is reading per line. Using this, you can put your text files values to your program.

This is a program I created for you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample2 {

//variable for file name with specified file path
private static final String FILENAME = "\*your directory*\filename.txt";
//List variable -> higher level of array because List is a flexible array
private static List<double> coordinates = new ArrayList<double>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {

        //this will add values from your textfile per line to List
        while ((coordinates.add(br.readLine())) != null) { }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This will solve one of your issue but this is just for you to move on not to solve all issues.

Your textfile should contain values like this

12

32

23

12

4 points for coordinates but per line. Your List coordinates will have it by running **while ((coordinates.add(br.readLine())) != null) { }**
research how to use list . It's a great thing to know.

Now study how to implement GUI using either JFrame or Applet.

Issues:

1. GUI : using JFrame
2. Read Text File : using BufferedReader
3. Array : using List, a higher level of array